# SQL server Profiler can be used any time?

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I want to run SQL Profiler for Long running queries in SQL server 2016. what is the best practice, without effecting the SQL performance in less time and more productive?

Comment: Use extended events, not profiler. While there is some overhead with XE, not nearly as much as profiler. Also might want to look at Query Store.

Comment: If you do use Profiler, don't run it on the DB server itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you use Extended Event instead of SQL Profiler trace.  Extended Events can be more targeted (regarding what you collect) and less impact on server resource ([Measuring “Observer Overhead” of SQL Trace vs. Extended Events](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/sql-trace/observer-overhead-trace-extended-events)). Few resources below which should give you a good start.

1. [SQL SERVER – Introduction to Extended Events – Finding Long Running Queries](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/03/29/sql-server-introduction-to-extended-events-finding-long-running-queries/)
2. [Finding One Problem Query With Extended Events](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/03/finding-one-problem-query-extended-events/)
3. [Three Ways to Identify Long Running Queries - PASS](http://www.pass.org/DownloadFile.aspx?File=20855c3d)

Comment: just now I got to know about "announcement from Microsoft:
We are announcing the deprecation of SQL Server Profiler for Database Engine Trace Capture and Trace Replay. These features are available in SQL Server 2016 but will be removed in a later version". So I prefer to use Extended Events. Thanks for response.